# I want to get sum of total reactions count of each user post .down i got the count of all reactions separately how to get total count of each user

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get the total count of all the reactions separately in another column. Below I got the Count of each reaction got by all the users. I want the output to have another column where it shows Michael --  totalReations = 4

[image]

I tried getting the count of each reaction type and now I want a separate count of all the reactions and I want all the previous elements as it is. Thank you so much for your time and help.

```
MATCH (z:User )-[re:REACTED] -> (p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(x:User) 
WHERE exists(re.type) 
RETURN x.name as postOwner, re.type as rectionType, count(re) as noOfReactions, collect(re.type);
```

Comment: This is neo4j/cypher right? If so it shouldn't be tagged with sql and mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MATCH (z:User )-[re:REACTED]->(p:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(x:User) 
WHERE exists(re.type) 
WITH x.name as postOwner, collect(re.type) AS reactions
WITH postOwner, size(reactions) AS totalReactions, reactions, reactions AS reactionsCopy
UNWIND reactionsCopy AS reactionType
WITH postOwner, totalReactions, reactionType, [x IN reactions WHERE x = reactionType | x] AS listOfMatchingReactions
RETURN postOwner, totalReactions, reactionType, size(listOfMatchingReactions) AS noOfReactions, listOfMatchingReactions
```

Here, we first collect all the reactions in a list. Then calculate it's size to get the total number of reactions. Then we unwind a copy of the list, and calculate the counts for each distinct type of reactions.